# How to create “lo-fi” images such as these?

Tags: image-quality

I only own Photoshop, so if anyone could let me know how to use Photoshop to create edits like this, it will be much help.

https://m.imgur.com/a/pkXmNCi?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app&utm_name=iossmf

Answer (score 1):

No one "owns" Photoshop any more `:)` everyone merely "rents" it (which is horrible)

---

Anyway...

Those images are simply **bad cell phone camera photos** or **low quality video snapshots**. That's how the camera took them. *Nothing* was "done" to them to make them look that way.

If you want something similar.. get a really low-end, circa 1995, video camera and take video, then grab some snapshots from the video.

Answer (score 0):

As it is hard to impossible to create high end images from a poor source there are plenty of filters and plugins to degrade image quality to any level. This also  includes creating fake video camera images.

To achieve any desired effect we need to think of the limitations our poor quality images have. For a low end video camera these are mainly the following:

- low **resolution** (NTSC would be 720 x 486 pixels, PAL 720 x 576 pixels)
- color **noise** from low end video chips
- **sharpening** artifacts from post-processing
- JPEG compression artifacts

All these artifacts can be added from almost any photo editing software. For a general access without the need of a commercial software I scaled an image to low resolution and then used the free to use [online tool set from G'mic](https://gmicol.greyc.fr/) with filters *Details > Sharpen*, *Filme emulation > Add grain*, *Degradation > JPEG artefacts*, each with rather exaggerating settings for the following outcome:

[image] 
<sup>[Source Image](https://www.deviantart.com/tak-kat/art/Follow-The-Masses-Uncertain-Path-XIII-763577233)</sup>

[image]
<sup>Degraded Image</sup>

If needed there are several other effects to further degrade an image. It can be fun to play with these and their settings.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an effect. I suspect these are just low resolution photos or video captures shot with a phone camera from several years ago. Anyway, it's easy enough to simulate it in Photoshop

Use a regular (present day) phone to take a photo.

1. Do *Image > Image Size*, take a note of the original size in pixels, ensure that the "Resmaple" option is checked.
2. Change the size to something much smaller.  In the example below I changed the width from 767px to 100px, and click OK. If your image is larger to begin with, you may need to experiment with the size to get the amount degradation you want.

[image]

3. Repeat *Image > Image Size*, but this time scale it up back to the original size you noted in step 1.

Here's the result (before and after)

[image]